# Why am I studying sea apples?

Tags: shark-game

I keep [studying them](http://cirri.al/sharks/#), but nothing seems to happen. Is there a point? How many sea apples would I have to study before something happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Studying sea apples converts them into science.  They are basically a consumable that give science, that can produced on an exponential scale (more planters gives more kelp per second gives more sea apples per-second-per-second).